# Executing a function (with a parameter) every X seconds in python

Tags: python

I want to run a code that runs a function with a parameter (eg. greet(h)) every 5 seconds. I tried using *threading* but it doesn't work. It executes just once. See the code below and the errors:

```
import threading

oh_hi = "Hi guys"

def greeting(hello):
    print "%s" % hello



threading.Timer(1, greeting(oh_hi)).start()
```

Error shown below:

```
> >>> ================================ RESTART
> ================================
> >>>  Hi guys
> >>> Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py",
> line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()   File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line
> 734, in run
>     self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Kindly assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the error is because you're not passing the proper arguments to the `threading.Timer()` method. Correcting that will run your function, once, after 5 seconds. There are a number of ways to get it to repeat.

An [object-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) approach would be to derive a new `threading.Thread` subclass. While it would be possible to create one that does specifically what you want -- namely `print "%s" % hello` -- it's only slightly more difficult to craft a more generic, parameterized, subclass that will call a function passed to it during its instantiation (just like `threading.Timer()`). This is illustrated below:

```
import threading
import time

class RepeatEvery(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, func, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval  # seconds between calls
        self.func = func          # function to call
        self.args = args          # optional positional argument(s) for call
        self.kwargs = kwargs      # optional keyword argument(s) for call
        self.runable = True
    def run(self):
        while self.runable:
            self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            time.sleep(self.interval)
    def stop(self):
        self.runable = False

def greeting(hello):
    print hello

thread = RepeatEvery(3, greeting, "Hi guys")
print "starting"
thread.start()
thread.join(21)  # allow thread to execute a while...
thread.stop()
print 'stopped'
```

Output:

```
# starting
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# Hi guys
# stopped
```

Besides overriding the base `threading.Thread` class's `__init__()` and `run()` methods, a `stop()` method was added to allow the thread to be terminated when desired. I also simplified the `print "%s" % hello` in your `greeting()` function to just `print hello`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the parameter `oh_hi` as a paramater itself to `threading.Timer` ... as stated in the documentation ...

`threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})`

To fix it you'd do ...

```
import threading

def greeting(hello):
    print "%s" % hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    oh_hi = "Hi guys"
    threading.Timer(1, greeting, args=(oh_hi,)).start()
```

Comment: threading.Timer() runs only once. It does not run every X time slots.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def greeting(hello):
    print "%s" % hello

while True:
    greeting(oh_hi)
    time.sleep(5)
```

If you want to use `threading.Timer`, keep in mind that you have to pass the parameter in this way (see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects)):

```
threading.Timer(1, greeting, (oh_hi,)).start()
```

The problem with your code is that `greeting(oh_hi)` is evaluated when the `Timer` object is being built. The function is executed but has no return value, and `None` becomes the second argument of `Timer`, that of course complains that `None` is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

```
threading.Timer(1, greeting(oh_hi)).start()
```

needs a function as the second parameter. Your code gives it `None` (the return value of the function `greeting(hello)`. You should use:

```
threading.Timer(1, greeting).start()
```

which however ignores the `oh_hi` parameter.

Reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) suggests:

```
threading.Timer(1, greeting, args=[oh_hi]).start()
```