# Is it safe to add a new method to Python Thread class?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to add a new method to a Thread subclass so I can tell my working thread to exit elegantly. Like this:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.__stop_signal = False
        self.__signal_lock = threading.Lock()
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...
        self.__signal_lock.acquire(True)
        stop_signal = self.__stop_signal
        self.__signal_lock.release()
        if stop_signal:
            return
        ...

    def stop_elegantly(self):
        self.__signal_lock.acquire(True)
        self.__stop_signal = True
        self.__signal_lock.release()
```

Then is it safe to do this?:

```
thread = MyThread()
thread.start()
...
thread.stop_elegantly()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks fine. In fact you could do it even more "elegantly" with:

```
def stop_elegantly(self):
    with self.__signal_lock:
        self.__stop_signal = True
```

Actually I don't think you even need a lock to access the member variable since there'll be a separate one allocated for each instance of your subclass. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564009/executing-a-function-with-a-parameter-every-x-seconds-in-python/5566638#5566638) for example, which adds a `stop()` method to the `threading.Thread` subclass.

Comment: Thank you. About the lock, I think in some extreme condition the lock is necessary(like when the value in memory is different from the value in cache). Of cause it's a little over-kill to use lock here.

Comment: @kkpattern: It seems to me that the cpu hardware would take care of any memory vs cached memory discrepancies within a single thread. Anyway, thanks for selecting my answer. BTW, it's customary here to also up-vote the answer you accept if you think it's worthy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.__signal_lock.acquire(True)
    stop_signal = self.__stop_signal
    self.__signal_lock.release()
```

The above code is in loop? If yes, I think it works well.

Comment: Sorry, I mean is it safe to call the method `stop_elegantly()` from another thread. The Python document says do not override methods other than `run()` and `__init__()`, but it doesn't say anything about add a new method and call it.

Comment: hmm. stop_elegantly() is called by main thread in your code, isn't it? I think main thread is another thread in your comment above.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is safe to call method from the Thread class, like `join()`, in the main thread. I want to know is it also safe to call a method added myself in a Thread subclass.